# Swift: transparent background for UIViewAlertController

Tags: ios, swift

there are many answers on Stack Overflow about this but none seem to work. how do you make the background color of a UIAlertViewController truly clear?

i have at the moment:

```
let errorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
let subview = errorAlert.view.subviews.first! as UIView
let alertContentView = subview.subviews.first! as UIView
alertContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
errorAlert.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
showViewController(errorAlert, sender: self)
```

but the result is a kind of white tinted, transparent-ish background over the image... **is there anyway to remove this tinted background?**

[image]

Comment: There are som many subviews in the alertcontroller that needs to be changed. Try to loop through al subviews and change their background color.

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve this the color of all subviews needs to be set to `UIColor.clear`. In addition, all `UIVisualEffectView` child views need to be removed. This can be accomplished by using a recursive function (Swift 4):

```
func clearBackgroundColor(of view: UIView) {
    if let effectsView = view as? UIVisualEffectView {
        effectsView.removeFromSuperview()
        return
    }

    view.backgroundColor = .clear        
    view.subviews.forEach { (subview) in
        clearBackground(of: subview)
    }
}
```

Call this right after creating the `UIAlertController` instance:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
clearBackgroundColor(of: alert.view)
```

If you now want to change the appearance of the alert:

```
alert.view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.6).cgColor
alert.view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
```

Comment: The only answer in the entirety of the internet that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the superview of the UIAlertController

```
alertView.view.superview?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: Also, the subviews of the UIAlertViewController need to be transparent or clear as well in order for the background to come through.

Comment: also a screen shot of youre seeing

Comment: looks like it's working exactly as I thought it would. The alert view controller background is slightly tented green (which is the color behind it). What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you're wanting to make the clear color more "clear" you can also set the alpha value of the UIColor.

Comment: "color more "clear"" exactly! ;-) which alpha? `subview.alpha = 0.0` in first for loop now removes everything!

Comment: In other words, you have successfully made your alert controller clear. The problem you have now is that you have a solid background behind it, so you will only be able to achieve a lighter version of that color. If you had image behind the alert view, you would notice a bigger variation and it would have that frosted look everyone loves.

Comment: but it also removed my text! ? (as i replaced the background with an image)

Comment: Look, the alpha value is going to change the transparency on your views. Instead of using clearColor() you can use an RGB value to set it to white (or whatever color you prefer) and change the alpha value anywhere from 0.0 to 1.0 (one being completely opaque). I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. The problem here is the flat green color behind the alert view. You can change the alpha value all you want, but the result you're going to get is a slightly lighter version of the green behind it, or nothing at all with an alpha value of 0.0.

Comment: Since you don't have an image, or gradient of any kind behind the alert view, you could also just find a lighter version of the same green color behind the view, and set the RGB values for the UIColor to the new green color you found.

Comment: i have an image, the constant greenColor() was just for convenience. i want the alert view to be transparent so that you can see the image behind it. but i want the text of the alert view to still be there. thanks.

Comment: Also, the superView is not a subview of the alert controller. It is the parent.

Comment: could you post a screen shot with the image behind it?

Comment: DO NOT MAKE YOUR SUBVIEWS A CLEAR COLOR. Only access the superview, and if need be change the opacity of the subviews. Revert back to what you had when you posted the screen shot, but replace the background with an image and lets see what we come out with.

Comment: The goal here is to make the superView's background completely clear. Once that is clear, you can set the subviews transparency so the background comes through.

Comment: Looks like apple keeps this locked down pretty tight. You can always create a custom alert controller using a UIViewController. You'll have more control over this. It will take some more time, but if you present it modally you'll have the same affect.

Comment: thanks for your help anyway. i've re-asked the question for clarity - perhaps some else knows how to do it ..

Comment: @PratyushPratik I just made a custom class, i.e. `AlertController(UIViewController)`